# Where is the Svelte bundle.js file when using https://github.com/sveltejs/template-webpack/?

Tags: webpack, svelte

When building Svelte using the default sveltejs/template (which uses Rollup), the bundle.js file can be found within the Svelte public directory of the code. However there is no sign of a 'physical' bundle.js file when building Svelte using the https://github.com/sveltejs/template-webpack/ codebase.

There is definitely bundle.js code when I build the webpack Svelte template and view http://localhost:8080/bundle.js, however a bundle.js never appears in my Svelte public file directory. **Does the bundle.js simple reside in memory when building Svelte with webpack?**

Answer (score 0):

It appears that webpack-dev-server serves assets in memory, so will not write the bundle.js to disk if we simply run the **npm dev** command. If we add a **"dev-build": "webpack"** command to the scripts element of the package.json file like so:

```
   "scripts": {
        "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --content-base public",
        "dev-build": "webpack"
      }
```

...then run **npm dev-build** from the command terminal, the bundle.js file will be written to disk (assuming you have the correct 'output' commands in the webpack.config.js file for your system).